# Python generated file not showing up in working directory

Tags: python, excel, windows, command-line-interface

I have a couple of Python scripts that are acting funny on my computer. A couple of colleagues use the same script and don't have any issues. Both scripts take a .csv as an input, make some transformations and then open a new .csv or Excel file.

One of them will open the new file, but it won't show up in the working directory; when you go to save the open file then it says the file already exists in the working directory. It allows you to replace it, but even after this is doesn't show up. A picture of that is below.
[image]

Here is the saving script for that:

```
result.to_csv('TypeMapping_filled_{}.csv'.format(str(datetime.date.today())), index=None, header=True)
os.startfile('TypeMapping_filled_{}.csv'.format(str(datetime.date.today())))
```

The other one will run the script, but the file won't open or show up in the directory. [image]

Here is the saving script for that:

```
styled_output.to_excel(f'REFORMATTED_{file_name[:(len(file_name)-4)]}.xlsx', index=None, header=True, engine='openpyxl')
```

Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Comment: Just wild wild guesses. The file is in the correct format? (.xls, .xlsx, .csv). The files are not hidden?

Comment: @Wizhi, the files are in the correct format and hidden files is checked in the working directory

Comment: If you're invoking `python.exe` from Windows PowerShell, try running `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD` just before calling python - Windows PowerShell doesn't automatically update the env working dir when you switch locations with `cd`/`Set-Location`

Comment: What version of python do you have? If it's less than I think 3.6 the f string won't work.

Comment: I would replace the paths in the script so that it's not directly `"file_name"` but `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "relative/movement/around/the/script/location", "file_name")`.